# Run pdflatex quietly

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm calling pdflatex from within my (C++) program using system(), needless to say all the garbage pdflatex puts on screen is a bit irritating in this case.

So...how do I encourage pdflatex to forego the lengthy outputs? 
It would be even better if only errors would be visible...

Comment: Relatex on tex SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27878/pdflatex-bash-script-to-supress-all-output-except-error-messages

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To simply ignore all output, redirect pdflatex stdout to /dev/null:

```
system("pdflatex yourdocument >/dev/null");
```

You may want to add `\nonstopmode` at the beginning of your document to instruct tex to keep going even when encountering errors.

To get the error messages, pipe pdflatex output to your program and look for errors around rows starting with `!`, e.g.

```
FILE *outputf = popen("pdflatex yourdocument", "r");

// ... read and analyze output from outputf ...

pclose(outputf);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if pdflatex does, but many command-line programs write to both stdout (which will be captured by your ">/dev/null") and stderr (which won't). To silence *both*, add " 2>&1" after your existing system() string.

Comment: Also: On Windows, the necessary device is just called "NUL" (note 1 "L"), not "/dev/null". The "2>&1" part works as for *nix.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you have an error, pdflatex stops, waiting for input, but you would never understand it. Will Robertson's answer is better (although pdflatex still outputs a couple lines)

Answer (score 70):

Unfortunately (La)TeX doesn't really abide by the rules of `stdout` and `sterr`, owing (I assume) to its origins in the early 80s. But there are some switches you can invoke to alter the amount of information being shown.

Execute `latex` with either the `-interaction=nonstopmode` or `-interaction=batchmode` switches for non-halting behaviour even in the case of a syntax error. `nonstopmode` will print all usual lines, it just won't stop. `batchmode` will suppress all but a handful of declarative lines ("this is pdfTeX v3.14...").

These can also be invoked from within the document with `\batchmode` and `\nonstopmode`, but this is less useful for the situation you're describing.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't really abide by the rules of `stdout` and `stderr`?"  Does it use other output streams?

Comment: @Matthew it's been a while since I looked at this, but my memory is that trying to redirect only, say, the error messages somewhere doesn't work at all. But I could be mistaken; sorry to be vague.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: by accident I found [Re: silencing latex (quiet/batch mode)?](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-09/msg00520.html); I believe that clarifies? Cheers!

Comment: one problem with `-interaction=batchmode` is that now errors do not show on the screen any more as well. One has to go look in the log file to see them, which is not convenient having to do each time to find if the file compiled OK or not.

Comment: I just had to add that Unix had stdout and Doug Mcllroy put in pipes long before the 1980s so I don't understand the comment about Latex having origins in the '80s as an excuse. I was around for all that, it just wasn't done well.